# Having trouble creating a record from a form select with associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select, model-associations

I'm new at Ruby on Rails and have been struggling through for a while now. Specifically my issue is that I have two tables: appointments and service1s. Service1 has_many :appointments and Appointment belongs_to :service1.

On my site, users can sign up for an appointment. In that form they can select a service as such:

```
<%= f.label "Service" %>
  <%= f.select :service1, options_from_collection_for_select(Service1.all, :id, :name), :prompt => true %>
```

In the appointments controller I have:
    def create
@stylists = ["Zoe Andreadis", "Amanda Giorgi", "Michelle Oda", "Danny Quaranta", "Demi Tsionis", "Christina Vicencio", "Nancianne Warren"]

```
 @appointment = Appointment.new(params.require(:appointment).permit(:date, :start, :stylistpref))
@appointment.service1 = Service1.find_by_name(:service1).id
@appointment.user = current_user
if @appointment.save

  flash[:success] = "Appointment Booked for " + @appointment.date + @appointment.time
  redirect_to(root_url)
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

The f.select stores the name as string, and I'm pretty sure the appointment model requires the id. 
With that code I get this error message on the @appointment.service1 line: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

If i get rid of that line, then I get the flash error message that service1 was left blank.

Please help me solve this!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Service1 with the name 'service1'. `find_by_name` is coming back with `nil`

**Update in response to your comment**:

That first code snippet you posted: that's within a form, correct? I think you want `params[:object_key][:service1]` where `:object_key` is the name of the record the form is based on.

I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to do what you're doing though. I'd have to see more code though.

Comment: Thank you,So how to do I get it to take the input from the f.select and pass it to find_by_name?

Comment: Yes it's in a form_for(@appointment). Would I put that in the form or controller'